# Live search on millions of records

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, search, full-text-search

#### What I need:

Consider a list of **7 million** objects of this type:

```
public class Item
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public List<Person> People { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Tags { get; set; }
    public List<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    public float Rating { get; set; }
    public int Yar { get; set; }
    public long Visits { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I want to be able to run a live search (either "StartsWith" or "Contains") on all of the records. By "Live Search" I mean when the user types the results should be suggested (like Google). I want to be able to run on multiple fields or a combination of them.

#### What I tried so far:

I tried using Linq to query database directly. Like this:

```
await db.Items.Include(i => i.People).Where(i => i.Name.Contains(query) || i.People.Any(p => p.Name.Contains(query))).ToListAsync();
```

But it was too slow. Then I tried caching them in memory. It was around 8GB of RAM but in addition to a **very** slow caching process at the start of the website and hard maintenance, the queries were still slow.

By caching I mean loading everything on these tables at the start of the website into memory and querying using Linq on the memory database.

What I think is needed, is some kind of tree-based indexing of documents. However, I don't know any good libraries / methods to do this.

Should I use a full-text search engine? I see websites doing it all the time.

#### PS:

I use MongoDb to store the data. Previously I had the data on the SQL Server database but the items were too complex and using a non-relational DB improved the performance a lot.

Comment: I highly recommend you to use ElasticSearch or Azure Search for this purpose.

Comment: a Trie works well for this type of problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie

Comment: Mongodb offers Atlas Search now, fully managed Lucene search in the aggregation pipeline.  https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/atlas-search

Answer (score 1):

You will need some kind of index to make this work well.

If `.StartsWith` is sufficient then performance should be acceptable if there is an index. I assume that `.StartsWith` should be translated to `WHERE Column1 LIKE 'abc%'`, and this should use the index, and therefore probably be fast enough. At least on SQL databases. I'm not sure how MongoDb index its data.

As far as I can tell `.Contains` will not be able to use the index, thus require a full table scan, and horrible performance as a result.

Alternative methods would be to use something like [ElasticSearch](https://www.elastic.co/) or write your own search structure.

Edit:
Another alternative could be [Lucene.net](http://lucenenet.apache.org/)

Comment: Does ElasticSearch work with "Contains"? If it doesn't, I might need to ditch it in favor of performance.

Comment: @alireza noon I have not used elastic Search, but I would be surprised if does not support "contains".

Answer (score 1):

So you have a string, that you call query, and this string changes with the typing speed of the operator: whenever the operator adds / removes / changes at least one character from query, you want to provide visual feedback to this operator.

This visual feedback doesn't have to be the full "Items with all their People", especially when the operator starts typing, and the query results in hundreds of items.

The only thing that you need to display is the text on which the operator decides what to type next.

Only when the operator indicates that he finished typing, you need to execute the full query, to show the full results.

### Improve the query while typing

**While typing fetch only properties that the operator needs to know what to type next.**
Does the operator need to know the Yar, Rating, Visits, etc while he is typing? Or does he only need to know the Item's Name? Or maybe the Item's name + Names of all People?

**While typing, does the operator need to see more then, say 20, results?**
Will he inspect these results while he is typing, or will he continue typing until there are only a few results?

**When using Entity Framework, a Select is usually faster then fetching complete objects.**
Don't transfer items that you won't use, like foreign keys, if you also have the primary key that the foreign key refers to. Furthermore: a Select won't check whether the data is in the DbContext.ChangeTracker, nor put it after the query in the ChangeTracter.

Keeping these three advices in mind, consider to change your query while typing:
(leaving out the async-await part, not part of the problem)

```
string operatorText = ...
var namesToShow = db.Items.Where(item => item.Name.Contains(operatorText)
                    .Select(item => item.Name)
                    .Take(20)
                    .ToList();
this.ShowVisualFeedBack(namesToShow);
```

Only if the operator presses enter, or the OK button:

```
string operatorText = ...
var itemsToShow = db.Items
    .Where(item => item.Name.Contains(operatorText
                || item.People.Any(person => ...)
                    .Select(item => item.Name)
                    .ToList();
```

### While typing, fetch the data "per page"

If you think that the operator wants to type only a few characters and then scroll through a list of a few hundred results, consider to fetch the data "per page", for instance with 20 items per page.

While the operator types, you only fetch the first page

```
string operatorText = ...
IQueryable<Items> itemsWithPeople = ... // see improved query above
                  .Take(20).
                  .ToList();
```

After typing some characters, the operator decides to start scrolling through the results.
To fetch page[i]:

```
IQueryable<TSource>FetchPage<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source,
    int pageNr, int pageSize)
{
    return source.Skip(pageNr * pageSize).Take(pageSize);
}
```

Some database management systems don't allow to Skip an unsorted sequence. In that case order by Id, or Name, before you Skip and Take.

### Add an extra index on names

I'm not really familiar with Mongo. Can you add extra indices?
If so, consider to index the Names. This will make a search on Names much faster.
If you can add separate tables, make a separate ItemName table with a one-to-many relation to the items that have this name.

Similar a peopleNames table.

### Prefetch the data

You suggested to prefetch some data. Consider to prefetch only the Id and Names, and put them in a LookupTable, with Names as key, Ids as values. If this leads to too many keys, because you have so many items, consider to put only the first few characters of the name as Key.

In that case: while typing for instance the first five characters, use the lookup table to showing about 20 eligible items.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer. Yes, MongoDB has extra indices. I'll look into your points. Also, I think the ElasticSearch that Jonas pointed out might be a good option in combination with your answer.